# Is there a way to disable any key and trackpad press power on for 2018 or later MacBooks?

Tags: macbook-pro, power

Oddly, 2018 or newer MacBooks by default power on when Off (a.k.a in the shutdown state) with [any key-press or track-pad button press](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201150#turnon) not just the power button or touch ID area as would be traditionally expected. Is there a way to disable this feature so that only pressing the power button / touch ID area cause the computer to power on?

**Ways to  Turn On, boot from the off state according to the Apple Documentation, without pressing the power button**

> *Newer Mac notebooks also turn on when you do these things:*
>
> - Open the lid of your Mac, even if it's not connected to power.
> - Connect your Mac to a power adapter while its lid is open.
> - **Additionally, MacBook Pro and MacBook Air models introduced in 2018 or later turn on when you press any key on the keyboard or press the trackpad.**

Comment: I've reviewed the link you posted to Apple's documentation. From what you describe this is expected behavior for wake from sleep. I would not expect this to happen if the computer is completely powered off (Eg. Apple Menu > Shut Down). So, to be clear, are we on the same page there, wake from sleep vs cold boot?

Comment: This is also an industry standard.  I’ve been waking (from sleep) Windows desktops and even Unix workstations from sleep with the “any key press” or a press of the mouse/track pad button for years. I wouldn’t be surprised if it were a feature request.

Comment: This is not wake from sleep question. This is Power on or cold boot up or as the apple documentation calls it Turn On, from the Off state, aka any key press powers the MacBook on from the Off state.

Comment: Found out about this when trying to wipe dust off the keyboard. And was wondering why the computer keeps on starting even after I just shut it down. Not really a big deal, but this seems like a great way to have your laptop unintentionally boot automatically while traveling, what was Apple thinking on making this a thing...